# Cannot get True when finding a number in a list that is divisible by 7

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def divisible_by_7(lst: List[int]) -> bool:
    """Return True if and only if lst contains an element divisible
    by 7. Otherwise, return False.

    >>> divisible_by_7([4,8,21,6])
    True
    >>> divisible_by_7([1,2,8,9])
    False
    """
    for num in lst:
        if num % 7 == 0:
            return True
        elif num % 7 !=0:
           return False
```

I keep on getting false even if the answer is true. I know that if we return false it won't work because when the function looks through the list, if there is even one instance where there is a number that isn't divisible by 7, it fails. How do I correct this?

Comment: Well, you trying only first element of the list, not all of them.

Comment: You are returning *on the first iteration*. You will only ever check the first number in the list

Comment: So how would i check all of the numbers?

Comment: By not returning if the decision is not yet made. (Hint: To not end up with an empty `if` or `elif` block, which would not be syntactically correct, look up what `pass` or `continue` do)

Comment: Imagine a group of people and you would want to find out if any of them is born in July by asking them one after another. If you asked the first person, and their answer was "no", would you conclude that *none* of them is born in July? Imagine how you would proceed and try to apply that to your code.

Answer (score 1):

How about to iterate thought all list elements?

```
def divisible_by_7(my_list):
    for num in my_list:
        if num % 7 == 0: 
            return True;
    return False;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning from the first iteration. The comments and [Oleg Butuzov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494869/cannot-get-true-when-finding-a-number-in-a-list-that-is-divisible-by-7/46494952#answer-46494930) have you covered there. However, the built-in shortcut for this pattern would be `any`:

```
def divisible_by_7(lst):
    return any(x % 7 == 0 for x in lst)
```